# spidermonkey 1.8.5 this object in function

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

While with spidermonkey 1.7 this object was working as expected in functions, with 1.8.5 always defaults to global object.

I am evaluating scripts to specific object and i expect this to be that object in functions as it did with 1.7.

for example

```
function dummy()
{
  alert("This: "+this);
}
```

with 1.7 will display "This: [object doc]"
1.8.5 will "This: [object global]"

Spidermonkey api call is made like:
JS_EvaluateUCScript(Ctx, jsobj, Code, Length(Code), nil, 0, nil) 
where jsobj is an object other than global object

Comment: The underlying behaviour is identical. They've just improved the message that gets reported.

Comment: I was misuse api call
JS_SetOptions(.., JSOPTION_VAROBJFIX | xxxx);

JSOPTION_VAROBJFIX should not be set, after removing i end up with 1.7 behavior